# kernel building errors investigation

Tags: kernel, compiling, logs

Tried to built kernel using this simple guide: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel
I've got only one "...all.deb" file instead of 3 files.
How can I track errors?
Are there any logs of compiling process or should I tee all output next time?

Comment: You should only have one "...all.deb" file. You should have 3 "*.deb" files. Yes, with that method of building the kernel, it can be a little difficult to isolate build errors. Always start by compiling the kernel with no changes at all, just to prove you can, then move on.